# how make this two 'separated' lans/networks see each other/works as one?

Tags: networking, routing, lan, static-routes, static

I need that devices from network 1 see/interact with devices on network 2, but i don't know how to do it.

[image: lan map]

1 - the modem of the contracted company is currently in bridge mode, because i don't have much access to his configurations and the company can change configurations without my authorization, so i keep it in this mode, and if is possible i like to keep it at this, but if really need i can change is mode.

2 - is not possible reorder physically the routers/modems, so the change must be logical

3 - in the end i only need access some shared folder on PC1 from PC4, and access the security camera live feed that is on NETWORK1 from a PC of NETWORK2, i can do that already in PCs/devices on NETWORK1 but not on NETWORK2

4 - i tried setting a fixed route but no success, i even change the modem back from BRIDGE to IP DHCP server to try....no success

Routers Options for static route:

[ARCHER C20 BR static route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLA51.png)

[ARCHER C20 BR static route possible configuration in BR version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m5q2.png)

[TL-WR641G/TL-WR642G BR static route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXR56.png)

[TL-WR641G/TL-WR642G BR static route possible configuration in BR version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYgup.png)

Modem config:

[Modem mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LAtf.png)

[Modem possible location for static route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHSeM.png)

[Modem possible location for static route options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNimo.png)

[Modem port triggers config, useful?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrC2W.png)

=====EDIT

with the modem in bridge mode each router was a external/internet IP and gateway different, but still no lucky, even after i change to DHCP server with NAT and now router 1 and 2 was a fixed IP and gateway one cant see each other: actual config:

[image]

please help me i am trying really hard....but this just dont work....

Comment: The modem screenshots for "port forwarding" are not about routes at all – they're about DNAT. (It's actually possible that the modem doesn't allow configuring static routes... Fortunately, you probably don't them on the modem anyway.)

Comment: Overall, your static route configuration seems correct; can you confirm that 192.168.0.2 is the ARCHER C20 and 192.168.0.3 is the TL-WR641G? However, the route settings shouldn't be showing "Status: Disabled" like in your screenshot – can you try changing that?

Comment: There is a lot you seem to be missing. The key problems to grasp are that there us NAT occuring on your tplink routers and modem, and that rather then looking at routers as having IP addresses, interfaces do....

Comment: I dont know that its possible to do in the tplink firmware, but the most logical solutiin is to turn off nat on the tplink routers and add appropriate routes on all the royters so they can see the other routers...

Comment: The alternative is to turn the tplink routers into APs by disabling dhcp and moving the wan cable to a lan port in both. Assuming the modem is running a dhcp server - which is likely - the networks would be renumbered into 192.168.0.x

Comment: @user1686 the images are only to show the possible configurations on this routers, the actual data are left from the last time i tried and they are all wrong in the images, but i already tried put the 'right' configurations and did not work.....

Comment: @davidgo the company modem is in bridge mode with everything disable, that way each router connected in the company modem was direct access to internet and was his on external/internet IP, DHCP/NAT is active in each router...... 

what i don't understand is, even changing the company mode to server DHP , now the router have a LAN IP from subnet of company modem and the routers with static routes set .....still don't see each other.....

and i really do not want enable any config on company modem

Comment: The WAN IP address that the routers receives are they static? You'll need to create rules in each router to allow the IP address of the other router access. So if they are dynamic this might be hard to do.

Comment: @GeekyDaddy i changed the mode of the company modem, now they have fixed gateway and IP but still no ping: https://i.imgur.com/dk98VRU.png

Comment: The way you have it setup, it's considered two separate network. The best way to setup is to use a VPN between the two routers. [How to securely join two networks together over the Internet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/14169/how-to-securely-join-two-networks-together-over-the-internet)

Comment: two options 1) can you put a cable between to routers? 2) if not, can you create routes in the Arris modem.

Answer (score 0):

From your image we don't know the addresses on the network between modem and both TPLink routers when the modem is in bridge mode. You included only the screen for NAT Route mode, where modem is 192.168.0.1 and TPLinks are 192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3. In bridge mode probably both TPLinks acquire completely different addresses from your provider's IP address pool.

However, regardless of what the addresses will be, in both setups each of the TPLink routers is independently doing it's own NAT. Connecting from one network behind a NAT to another network behind another NAT through external network (and network between modem and TPLinks is exactly that in this case) is impossible directly. As suggested in one of the comments, you may try to setup VPN between the routers, but I don't know whether your TPLinks support it. And also for this case it seems like an overkill for me. VPNs are meant to use with geographically separated locations that can't be connected directly.

I see two (or even three) options for you:

1. Set your modem to NAT Route mode, not bridge mode, **and** use TPLinks not as routers, but as switches. I guess they have multiple ports on the LAN side? So turn off the DHCP server on TPLink so that the modem is only one DHCP server in your network, and plug the cable coming from the modem into LAN side of the TPLink, and not into WAN side. All the devices on wired connections will get their IP addresses from the modem and in fact they will be on a single network 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0. However, I don't know if wireless connection will work in this setup. That depends on the specifics of the router.
2. If this is possible, turn off NAT in both TPLinks. Set your modem to NAT Route mode as in solution 1. The static routes you tried to add on your TPLinks should be working now.
3. Buy another router to interconnect the two networks. This router must allow to **turn off** the NAT functionality. Turn NAT and DHCP on the new router off, plug one side of the new router into LAN side of one TPLink, other side of the new router into LAN side of the other TPLink, and set the IP addresses on both sides like for example 192.168.2.20 and 192.168.8.20 (I suppose from your picture that your TPLinks are dynamically assigning addresses starting from 100, so there will be no conflict). Add on WR a static route to 192.168.8.0/255.255.255.0 via 192.168.2.20 and on Archer to 192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0 via 192.168.8.20. There is a small chance that adding these routes on routers will not work and you have instead to add them on all individual devices in both networks.

Hope this helps.